# Incident SLA through Rest API

Tags: api, rest, servicenow

there is one way to extract sla from a service now rest api call?
I need to extract from service now all the sla related to my incident. Is there one way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

SLA data is stored in the `task_sla` table. You an use the Table API. Execute a `GET` on the table `task_sla` using `sysparm_query=task=xxx` where `xxx` is the `sys_id` of your Incident.